# How to add FastMM to a C++ Builder project?

Tags: c++, c++builder, fastmm

I'm trying to configure `FASTMM4` for `Builder C++ 6` and the steps I followed are;

1. Downloaded zip from [sourceforge.](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fastmm/)
2. Under the `Project -> Options -> Linker` menu I unchecked `"Use Dynamic RTL"`.
3. Unzipped the contents at `C:/tools/FASTMM` and added `FASTMM4.pas` file to my test C++ VCL project.
4. Simply compiled the unit from Project menu and got a new `FastMM4.hpp` file in FastMM folder.
5. Included `FastMM4BCB.cpp` file in my project and also wrote `#include <FASTMM4.hpp>` on the top.
6. Added path to `FastMM_FullDebugMode.dll` and `FastMM_FullDebugMode.lib` and moved `FastMM_FullDebugMode.dll` to the `Bin` folder in `Builder C++` install directory.
7. Enabled the line `{$define FullDebugMode}` from `FastMM4Options.inc`.

Did I miss anything? why do I have the following errors?

[image: LINKER ERRORS]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the instructions in FastMM4BCB file itself and I got it working.

Usage:

1. Copy FastMM4BCB.cpp, FastMM4.pas, FastMM4Message.pas, FastMM4Options.inc,
   and FastMM_FullDebugMode.lib to your source folder.
2. Copy FastMM_FullDebugMode.dll to your application's .exe directory (if you
   intend to use FullDebugMode).
3. To your project, add FastMM4Messages.pas first, then FastMM4.pas, then
   FastMM4BCB.cpp. On compiling the .pas files, .hpp files are created and
   imported by the subsequent files.
4. Add USEOBJ("FastMM4BCB.cpp") to your project file, BEFORE any other
   USEFORM directives.
5. Under the Project -> Options -> Linker menu uncheck "Use Dynamic RTL"
   (sorry, won't work with the RTL DLL).

   FastMM will now install itself on startup and replace the RTL memory manager.